# get array of data for one record in psql?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have two table which are person and account .

person has id and name.

```
+----------+--------+--------------------------------------------+
| Column   | Type   | Modifiers                                  |
|----------+--------+--------------------------------------------|
| id       | bigint |  not null generated by default as identity |
| name     | text   |                                            |
```

and account has id, name, ids

```
 +----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
| Column   | Type      | Modifiers                                  |
|----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------|
| id       | bigint    |  not null generated by default as identity |
| name     | text      |                                            |
| ids      | integer[] |                                            |
+----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
Indexes:
    "account_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Check constraints:
    "account_ids_check" CHECK (array_length(ids, 0) < 4)
```

- I'm storing id of person in ids.
  I have two questions:

1. my ids filed in account table can be array of foreign key and point to person's id? if yes how can do It?
2. I want to get the id and name of account and name , id of person of the id that is in ids. like this .

   id:
   name:
   ids: [{id: ,name: },{id: ,name: },{id: ,name: }]

I'm using this query but it gives me error

```
SELECT aa.id,
          aa.name,
          array(SELECT json_build_object ( 'id', p.id,'name', p.name  from  person p JOIN  account a ON  p.id = ANY(a.ids) ) ) as pins
  from  account aa where aa.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

### [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=26f5371838317392af5d9b4182aa65d2)

I refactored your code. Hope it can solve your problem.
basically my code idea is one person cannot have more than 4 accounts.
one account belong to multi person seems not that intuitive to me.

---

some columns to json => https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69655/select-columns-inside-json-agg and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90858/postgres-multiple-columns-to-json

---

```
begin;
create table person
    (person_id bigserial primary key,
    name text not null,
    account_ct integer default 0,  constraint account_ct_max4 check( account_ct BETWEEN 0 AND 4 ));
create table account(
    account_id serial primary key,
    account_type text,
    account_limits numeric,
    person_id bigint,
    constraint person_ref_fkey foreign key (person_id)
    references person(person_id) match simple
    on update cascade on delete cascade
);
commit;
```

idea is a person can have multi account, but no more than 4. We use trigger to enforce that.

```
--tojson one person's account info.
select p.person_id,
       p.name,
       json_agg( 
(select x from (select a.account_id, a.account_type) as x) ) as item
    from account a join person p on a.person_id = p.person_id
where p.person_id = 1
group by 1,2;



--tojson one person's person info. account info not convert to json. 
select account_id,
       account_type,
      json_build_object('id',p.person_id,'name',p.name)
from account a, person p
where p.person_id = 1;
```